# Laravel URL::asset issue

Tags: html, laravel

I have this code in HTML

```html
<li class="user-footer">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <a href="{{ URL::route('logout') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

My question is, why href URL is generating [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlTkS.jpg)

I'm using Laravel 5.5.

Comment: Try changing it to ``{{ url('logout')}}``

Comment: The code looks ok. Maybe the error lies in a part of the view you are not showing

Comment: Try `{{ url('/logout') }}`

Comment: Silly question. Does the view have the extension ".blade.php" ? Because it should.

Comment: share your full view

Comment: Another ask and run has been perpetrated :'(

Comment: use `{{ url('/logout') }}` :)

Comment: thanks @Amarnasan. I have part "{{ URL::" without closing it in these line before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your error you are trying to call Named Routes.

You should have route like this to use Named Routes (if you don't already have).

```
    Route::get('user/logout', 'UserController@logout')->name('logout');
```

And your view should be like this:

```
<li class="user-footer">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Laravel Named Routes document: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes